# Ungrouped data. Mean, standard deviation and variance

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

Could someone please tell me if i have done this correct please? I have attempted this twice before and it has been incorrect. I know the mean is correct. Its the Standard deviance and variance i've struggled with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, you have it right. Without approximating the mean you get Var($X$)=$0.0001650404$, and Sd($X$)=$0.01284681$, so you have done it correct.

Comment: The answer is correct, but not what you did in the operation: $S$ is the deviation, and when you say it is equal to $0.000168$ that's not true, that's not square-rooting it. So $S=\sqrt{0.000168}=0.012961$, being $0.000168=S^2$.

Comment: @Alfredo So i have just mixed up the $$S^2$$ and  $$S$$? So is the edit i have made correct?

Comment: Indeed. $S^2 = \dfrac{\sum f(x-\bar{x})^2}{\sum f-1} = \dfrac{0.0167}{99} = 0.000168$

Comment: Then $$ S = 0.0002313 $$

Comment: No, $S=\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum f(x-\bar{x})^2}{\sum f-1}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{0.0167}{99}}=\sqrt{S^2}= 0.012961$